# Folders not showing up on disk from XCode

Tags: xcode

I added a folder to my project in XCode and called it Themes, which will be used to store themes for my iPad app. Under that I have Red,Blue, and so forth.

They show up in XCode. But when I look at the physical folder, there is no Themes directory (and obviously anything under it).

Why not? Where did it go? How can I store images (which may have same names) under different paths (themes)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XCode does not create "folder", it creates "groups". Groups are logical organization of your files, independent of the file system organization underneath it

If you want to actually have a folder, easiest way would be to create one on the file system first (through Finder), and then drag it to XCode's project navigator. When a confirmation window pops up, leave the default settings (*"Copy items into destination"* and *"Create groups for any added folders"*)

This will import the folder and all the files in it, however it will not auto-import newly added files to the folder after this (you'd have to manually add them).

If you do want to auto-import newly added files from the file system's folder to this group in XCode, instead of using *"Create groups for any added folders"*, change to *"Create folder references to any added folders"*

Comment: thank you. I didn't know how that worked. this made it clear.

Comment: While this is technically the easiest way, its still a pain. Xcode really needs an option to create physical folders for created groups