# Unable to see image files in xcode folder reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added a folder which contains some images in Xcode as "Create folder references for any added folders". It added the blue folder but it doesn't show the arrow to see its contents.
Is this an issue in Xcode or am I missing something ?

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: have you checked the Destination Copy items into destination group's folder and Add to targets?

Comment: Yes, the images are copied and added to the target and they are being used successfully in the app. The only issue is I am not able to see images in xcode folder.

Comment: its weird,maybe there is something wrong in your xcode. have you tried to restart xcode?

Comment: Yes I restarted my xcode so many times but no luck. I created a sample project and added the same folder and there is no issue.

Comment: You have to add your resources outside lproj(Linked Project). This is wrong. Add the outside. You should be able to access them.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda I tried your solution but its not working. Is there any setting that we have to do in xcode for this ?

Comment: @iVipS - may be same as like your question ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851801/folders-not-showing-up-on-disk-from-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Blue folder means you added folder reference ,not folder

Right click on the images folder you added and  select `show in finder`...See if the images are there..if not.. you linked the wrong folder

Make sure the search bar at bottom of the file explorer is empty

Comment: Images are there in this folder and I am using these images too. The only issue is that I can not see these images in xcode under this folder otherwise everything is going fine.

Comment: One doubt,Why add folder reference?why didnt add folder?

Comment: Actually I have two folders which consist images with same names. In code, I just mention folder name to pick these images. So this is the requirement thats why I added them as folder references.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the folder in a wrong way. To create a reference folder select the checkbox

```
'Copy items into destination's group folder if needed'
```

and in folder options select the radio button

```
 "Create folder references for any added folders".
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use blue folder references for your resources these folders will also be created inside your application bundle, while resource files in groups will simply be copied to your mainBundle's root directory.

When folder structure is managed outside of XCode (for example, a cross-platform project which has project files for different versions of XCode, Visual Studio and other IDEs, all using mostly the same directory tree), you normally want folder references. Otherwise one would have to recreate every project file every time folder structure changes.

**This is Your solution->**
if you do want to auto-import newly added files from the file system's folder to this group in XCode, instead of using "Create groups for any added folders", change to "Create folder references to any added folders"